# Returning all dates from a string

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to get all dates from lists of long strings, each string has several dates and with different formats, I want to grab them all. I tried both `datefinder` and `dparser`

```
import datefinder
import dateutil.parser as dparser
input_string = 'the document is valid from 2018-11-20 until 2021-11-19, or 25 October 2020 until 25 October 2021, or 3/14/2020 to 3/13/2021, or April 4, 2015 until April 3 2018, or 3rd March 2007 to 4th March 2008'
print(list(datefinder.find_dates(input_string)))
print(dparser.parse(input_string,fuzzy=True))
```

output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2007, 3, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 3, 4, 0, 0)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1244-b5979411a38b> in <module>
      4 print(list(datefinder.find_dates(input_string)))
      5 
----> 6 print(dparser.parse(input_string,fuzzy=True))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1372         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1373     else:
-> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1375 
   1376 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         if res is None:
--> 649             raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
    650 
    651         if len(res) == 0:

ParserError: Unknown string format: the document is valid from 2018-11-20 until 2021-11-19, or 25 October 2020 until 25 October 2021, or 3/14/2020 to 3/13/2021, or April 4, 2015 until April 3 2018, or 3rd March 2007 to 4th March 2008
```

`datefinder` found 4 dates out of the 10 dates in the string, `dparser` does recognize them individually if the string has one date, but with several dates in one string it returns error

PS: formats are not limited to the ones in the example, also these strings are pulled out by `pytesseract` so there are wrong characters and some issues like that, so `regex` is a complicated choice and I'm looking for another better one

Comment: `dparser` would work too, but I need it to work on the entire string

Comment: seams like `datefinder` is blocklisting the word "until"